# Saber cuantos botones hay con un bucle y asignar funciones

Tags: javascript

Intento crear un bucle donde detecte cuántos botones hay, y a cada botón se le asigne una función:

```
var ff = f0.querySelectorAll("button");
      console.log(ff);

      for(let i = 0; i < ff.length; i++){
         if(ff[0].addEventListener("click", ()=>{
            console.log(i);
         }));
         if(ff[1].addEventListener("click", ()=>{
            console.log('adios');
         }));
         if(ff[2].addEventListener("click", ()=>{
            console.log('adiew');
         }));
      }
```

Con esta forma de hacerlo, se detecta y se hace clic, pero cuentan tantos clics como botones tenga el recorrido. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo, sabiendo que más tarde podría añadir otro botón?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si a cada botón le vas a poner un event listener distinto, puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
const ff = f0.querySelectorAll("button");
    
if (ff[0]) {
  ff[0].addEventListener("click", () => console.log(i));
}
if(ff[1]) {
  ff[1].addEventListener("click", () => console.log('adios'));
}
if(ff[2]) {
  ff[2].addEventListener("click", () => console.log('adiew'));
}
```

Si vas a poner a cada botón el mismo event listener puedes hacer

```
f0.querySelectorAll("button").forEach((button,index) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => console.log(index));
});
```

Comment: Pues mira si, mucho más corto. Modificado esta =3
Muchas gracias! Me estás ayudando una barbaridad

Answer (score 1):

Ya se me ocurrió la solución, el gran &&:

```
for(let i = 0; i < ff.length; i++){
         if(i==0&&ff[0].addEventListener("click", ()=>{
            console.log('Hola');
         }));
         if(i==1&&ff[1].addEventListener("click", ()=>{
            console.log('adios');
         }));
         if(i==2&&ff[2].addEventListener("click", ()=>{
            console.log('adiew');
         }));
      }
```

Por muchas veces que haga el recorrido el bucle, si pones como parámetro de salida que i sea igual estrictamente a 0/1/2 Y (**&&**) haga clic en X con el addEventListener, ya tenemos una asignación por número y función correctamente que sólo se ejecuta una vez.

Comment: Realmente no entiendo qué estás intentando, pero creo que te sobra todo el bucle for

Comment: El motivo del bucle for es porque detecta cuántos botones hay en un formulario. `ff.lenght`, lo pone como límite del bucle (son 3) y como yo se cuál es cual, le añado a mano la funcionalidad. Me dieron como consejo, que si en algún momento iba a tener que añadir un botón mas, o dos o tres, nunca me pensara el no usar el bucle for.